# Set type of a variable so it's the same as the contents of a set

Tags: python-3.x, string, set, python-typing

I want to be able to, through the python typing module and the python static type checker, set the type of a variable so that it matches the type inside a defined set.

I have looked around for a while now and I can't find a way to reference the original set such that it defines the type of the new variable. I could do something like the following where I just use the same type reference as the one inside the set declaration...

```
my_set: Set[str] = {"a","b"}
def my_func(in_val:str):
   ...
```

but it would not be ideal.

Ideally I could do something like the following...

scratch1.py

```
import typing

my_set: typing.Set[str] = {"a","b","c"}

def my_func(in_val: TypeElement[my_set]):  # Or something like this
    print(in_val)

my_func("a")  # No error when running mypy
my_func(1)  # Error when running mypy
my_func("d")  # Possibly error, if possible, when running mypy
```

run in terminal

```
$ mypy scratch1.py
scratch1.py:9: error: Argument 1 to "my_func" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
```

Comment: What's wrong with hard-coding the `str` type? You've already hard-coded what `my_set` is assigned to, so it's not clear to me why you object to hard-coding the types of parameters that work with this variable. Can you clarify why you're trying to do this? Perhaps there's a solution that works better with your underlying use case.

Comment: The reason why I would want to reference "my_set" in the type for the input would be, whatever is in the set "my_set", I want to be able to match the type. In that case if someone is reading the code or if the contents of "my_set" changes for some reason, I would want people to understand that the reason for the input type is because of "my_set". The other reason I want to do this is because, I want in some function, to check if the input value is in the set. I am guessing this would be some logical check though through a function call.